# How to make Slide buttons in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey i am working on a css slider it is working fine without js only with css but i want to make a js script for navigation buttons for slider i mean i want to make a js script that can slide the content left or right by clicking on left or right button and it has to make a loop i mean if you click button once then it has to slide content left or right by 100% each time and max width is 1000% of the content which i want to slide can anyone please help me for this

```
<div class="slider-10">
<div class="slider-box" style="width: 1000%">
<img src="img/image-1.jpg" />
<img src="img/image-2.jpg" />
<img src="img/image-3.jpg" />
<img src="img/image-4.jpg" />
<img src="img/image-5.jpg" />
<img src="img/image-6.jpg" />
<img src="img/image-7.jpg" />
<img src="img/image-8.jpg" />
<img src="img/image-9.jpg" />
<img src="img/image-10.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
```

And i want to slide this section:

```
<div class="slider-box" style="width: 1000%">
    <img src="img/image-1.jpg" />
    <img src="img/image-2.jpg" />
    <img src="img/image-3.jpg" />
    <img src="img/image-4.jpg" />
    <img src="img/image-5.jpg" />
    <img src="img/image-6.jpg" />
    <img src="img/image-7.jpg" />
    <img src="img/image-8.jpg" />
    <img src="img/image-9.jpg" />
    <img src="img/image-10.jpg" />
    </div>
```

Please help me

Comment: why not just use an available third-party component like Bootstrap's carousel? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: No because i am making my own slider framework for the people who dont know js but i want it for me to add js for navigation of slider

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't require much JS. It's pretty much plug-and-play.

Comment: But i hate bootstrap i want my framework

Comment: why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: I want it simple and easy by not using js

Comment: but you just said you needed some javascript to make your slider buttons work...

Comment: Yeah but only for me not for everyone

Comment: But what have you tried so far? I think using only one `img` and toggling its `src` is the best way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

You can set any `img` in a `div` element means 1 `div` for every `img`tag then declare a function in js and call it with `onclick` event for EX: click right button sends 1 to function and left one -1.
then yo can add class for every div that should show.